# Error: Cannot find module 'C:\vite\bin\vite.js' when installing vue.js to Laravel project

Tags: node.js, laravel, visual-studio, vue.js, visual-studio-code

I wanted to learn Laravel and Vue.js so I tried installing both by following this tutorial: https://youtu.be/WLQDpY7lOLg?t=1058

Everything worked as it should until the npm run dev command...

These are the commands I ran in the Laravel project terminal(in the tutorial at 21:19)

```
npm init vite vue
cd vue/
npm install
npm run dev
```

This is the output that I get after running the last command

```
PS C:\Laravel&React Projects\laravel-vue-survey\vue> npm run dev

> vue@0.0.0 dev
> vite

'React' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:949
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\vite\bin\vite.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:946:15)
        at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:787:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v18.4.0
```

I'm trying to solve this issue for some hours now but still no luck... I hope someone knows how to make it work...

Comment: If it helps anyone: I had this error when I upgraded my projects to node version >18. Switching back to v16 fixed it.

Answer (score 16):

ugh...So i fixed the problem... If any1 else runs in something like that...First make sure you don't name your projects using characters such as (&,%,$,?...). Parent folder of this project had '&' in its name and that caused the error...

Comment: this works in my situation. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the question but laravel comes already integrated with Vuejs3.  You can fin these files on resources-->js-->pages i.e. Maybe if you can be more precise in the question could help.

Comment: When i first created Laravel project i only had app.js and bootstrap.js in the resources folder...
Simply i just want to create a working Laravel project with vue.js, i tried 3 tutorials so far and all seemed to fail... I'm guessing i need to install something but not sure what...

I tried deleting node_modules and package-lock.json and then running the "nmp install" command again, but it still wont work...

Comment: Did you resolve? i can help.